# Protractor Execution hangs when validating element not present in DOM

Tags: typescript, protractor

This is very strange that protractor execution hangs for infinite time while we are validating the test case is not present in dom.
Below are the code we tried but its hangs not sure why.
It keeps waiting for this.columnNamesInTableSingle element even though its not present in DOM and we needs to validate that only

```
 var el = this.columnNamesInTableSingle;
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.not(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(el)),5000);



expect(this.columnNamesInTableSingle.isPresent()).toBe(false);

 this.columnNamesInTableSingle.then(a=>{
    //         console.log(a.length+"==============================")
    //     },abc=>{
    //         console.log(abc)
    //     })
```

Comment: Try with the stalenessOf. No need to add the 'not'.http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf

Comment: I used but again its hangs there only and no error is thrown

Comment: Why are you waiting for it? Does it disappear due to some action? If not then just use the expect statement

Comment: I have a clear column links by clicking it will not display any column.
so wanted to test it by validating that no column is displayed but it didnt helped
i tried expect also but its hangs looking for that element

Comment: I'd like to see what you have in "this.columnNamesInTableSingle"

Comment: columnNamesInTableSingle=element(by.xpath('.//*[@ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"]'))

Answer (score 0):

i know that this post is very old but i've implemented a function that could be useful to test if elements are present (or not) in DOM without any `wait`:

3 parameters:

- field: the `ElementFinder | ElementFinder[]` targeted;
- fieldName: `string` name of target (just for log it);
- present: `boolean` to switch your control (test if present or not);

the function:

```js
export async function checkField(field: any, fieldName: string, present?: any) {
  let text: string;
  if (present === false) {
    if (field.length > 0) {
      field.forEach(async el => {
        try {
          text = await el.getText();
          expect('should not be present (' + fieldName + ')').toEqual('but it is');
        } catch (e) {
          expect(el.isPresent()).toBe(present);
        }
      });
    } else {
      try {
        text = await field.getText();
        expect('should not be present (' + fieldName + ')').toEqual('but it is');
      } catch (e) {
        expect(field.isPresent()).toBe(present);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (field.length > 0) {
      field.forEach(async el => {
        try {
          text = await el.getText();
          expect(el.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        } catch (e) {
          expect('is present (' + fieldName + ')').toEqual('but i can\'t find it');
          throw e;
        }
      });
    } else {
      try {
        text = await field.getText();
        expect(field.isPresent()).toBe(true);
      } catch (e) {
        expect('is present (' + fieldName + ')').toEqual('but i can\'t find it');
        throw e;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will be still useful (i know, could be written better)

If this works and gratify your question, please consider to close it!